# How to use otool to detect nonpublic apis in iphone and ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4.5

My app was rejected for the first time I submitted because of use of non public apis.So I wanted to make sure that I avoid using private apis in my code.I have gone through google and found that I can use otool to detect non public apis in our code .But Im confused how to use it.I dont find it clearly anywhere .I'm using Xcode 4.5

How can I use it to detect private api's in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Open Terminal ( Ctrl + Space -> Type 'Terminal')..

and print example:

otool -MVv yourlib.a
for help:

otool --help
```

Comment: Can u please tell me what is this "yourlib.a" Where can I find it ?

Comment: your downloaded library name

Comment: Sorry I didn't get u .From where should I download it ?

Comment: Read this : http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/otool.1.html